# MVC app hosting Angular app routing not working on first navigation

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm having an issue with navigating within an Angular app hosted on an MVC page, it is mostly working but 1 scenario is causing the URL to change but the app does not show the new page.

I'll try to break down the setup into it's simplest form, (this issue is occuring in large enterprise application)

We have an MVC application with 2 pages, home and app. Both have controllers and views. The home index.cshtml is a simple Razor view and the app index.cshtml only has the `<app-root></app-root>` element defined on it. Both views are using a base layout page that defines the navigation menu for the entire app.

In the Menu we have 4 anchor tags with:

- href="/home"
- href="/app/#/page1"
- href="/app/#/page2"
- href="/app/#/page3"

On the Angular side we have 3 pages (page1, page2 and page3). The routing is also fairly simple:

```
    Routes = [
    {
        path: 'page1',
        component: Page1Component,
    },
    {
        path: 'page2',
        component: Page2Component,
    },
    {
        path: 'page3',
        component: Page3Component,
    },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes , { useHash: true, enableTracing: true } )],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Now if I am on the home page and click the link to Page 1 everything works. The page changes, the angular app loads and everything is great.

If I now click on the link for Page 2, the URL changes but the angular app does not load the new component. (Looking at the console the router tracing doesn't show). Now that it is in this "error" state, I can click on Page 3 and it works. URL changes and page 3 component loads. If I now click on Page 2, it works as well.

The app will now navigate correctly until I move back to the home (MVC) page. From that point on we return to the above situation, first nav works, second nav doesn't (but URL updates) and all further navs work.

**Note:** If I add links on the angular pages (Page1, Page2 and Page3) and use the routerLink attribute then I don't see the issue. Only when using anchor tags with HRef does the issue arise.

Unfortunately as the navigation menu is on MVC base page (and it is a very large enterprise app) I can't rewrite this as Angular component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
            href="/app/#/pageX"
```

to

```
            href="/pageX"
```

Comment: But that won't work when navigating from the MVC page, as it needs to know the MVC route to load (app), which loads the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I have worked around this problem by adding an onclick handler to the links.

This simply sets the window.location.href value to be the same as the href value of the a tag.

Not sure why but it now navigates on first click and is smart enough not to do a full page refresh if navigating within the Angular app.

Doesn't feel like the right solution but the one that is working for now